# Rewrite Subdomain To non-existing Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

post edited with better current example.

I am looking for the best way to redirect my subdomains to subdirectories which do not really exist as subfolders.....

in a nutshell, the script I am using for a website allows for setting up geographic regions as subdomains..... but each region MUST have a unique subdomain and I really do not want to have 3-level subdomains (state, city, neighborhood) for my regions and the "big boys" in my niche all opt to use a single subdirectory (like /neighborhood-city,state/) so I am looking for the best way to point my subdomains to subdirectories, although they do not actually exist....

I currently have this in the htaccess as a rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([^./\\"'?#]+)\.html$  index.php?a=5&b=$1 [QSA,L] ##category
```

which rewrites to the url to: mydomain/cat#/catname.html

I want the URL/links to have this non-existing "region" subdomain-as-subdirectory added after the /catname/ but not sure how to modify this rewrite so that instead of having:

```
subdomain.mydomain/cat#/catname.html
```

I would have:

```
mydomain/cat#/catname/subdomain(value).html
```

Answer (score 2):

The not found error is normal because you redirect your subdomains to nonexistents directories, which are not rewrited. Besides your redirection, you have to rewrite these directories so that the server knows where it can find the real files. So, try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [L]
```

Of course, you have to change this path to the good.

Comment: +1 In addition to that I think OP would need to drop `[L]` from his existing rule.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But... Won't rewriting the directories to "where the real files are" in effect rewrite the URL back to the original subdomain or, if not, at least to the root domain instead?

Comment: No. Because, here, in my code, there are no redirection. Just a rewriting

Comment: thanks... I guess I am just not getting it, these rewrites are new to me. But, my goal of "simply" having the subdomain appear as a (non-existing) subfolder between the domain and index.php, ie domain.com/subdomain-turned-directory/index.php still isn't working. I edited out the "L" and played around with a few variations based on your last suggestion but, since there ISN'T a "real" folder path, everything I attempted got errors.....

Comment: Okay. So where the real files are located ? What is their path ? And from what path do you want to access to them ?

Comment: there are no real files per se... the subdomains are used for "regions", which are in the database, not a file or folder. The script allows me to give each region in the DB a unique name, which will also be used as the subdomain for that region. But, as mentioned, I really do not want 3-level subdomains and the competition also only uses a subdirectory for the regions, which I am hoping to do as well. basically, instead of having region.domain.com/index.php (or whatever would be there normally), I want to have domain.com/region/index.php etc.....

Comment: Ok and the domain.com/region/index.php file should point to the region.domain.com/index.php file ?

Comment: yes..... but of course without reverting to the "original" url that has a subdomain....

Comment: I really appreciate your tenacity and extended help, but is still not working. what I have now is:      RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [L]

Comment: Ah ok ! Replace your whole code with mine. So, you just have my code in your htaccess file.

Comment: thanks.... but using ONLY that code simply reverts to region.domain.com/index.php

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't help you more.

Comment: I understand and thank you again for your input. Wish it would have worked! Take care.

Comment: original post updated with actual page URL example. thanks for any input.